# Adding Guest Email Functionality for Magento Product Alert

Tags: php, magento

I am entirely new to Magento Development and I am attempting to add guest email signup ability to the Magento ProductAlert system. I have begun creating a module to extend the Mage_ProductAlert_AddController class and add functionality to the the stockAction function.

I have been looking at the Newsletter SubscriberController.php controller for inspiration on how to approach this issue while providing Zend_Validate, etc.

I have also created an email column within my product_alert_stock table.

I am now at a loss as to how to approach the rest of building out my module.